# Updating MySQL with input box -- PHP MYSQL HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, input

I need my input box to be able to read the current value from the database, but also be able to change that value.

When I input something into this inputbox such as 1000, it gets posted fine. My post results from PHP look like:

*Data updated col1 Supplies col2 col3 1000 col4 servicereq 2 owneremail test2 piemail test2 id1 466*

So the value for col3 = 1000, but it does not get entered into the mysql database. But for the dropdown menus (serreqid, owneremail, piemail) update in mysql fine.

How the input box is generated:

```
<form  action='insert.php' method='post'>    
<input type='text' name=col3 id=col3 value='$col3' size='11' onblur='this.form.submit()'>
```

Mysql update:

```
$col1=$_POST['$col1'];
$col2=$_POST['$col2'];
$col3=$_POST['$col3'];
$col4=$_POST['$col4'];
$serreqid = $_POST['servicereq'];
$owneremail = $_POST['owneremail'];
$piemail = $_POST['piemail'];
$id1 = $_POST['id1'];

$sql = "UPDATE reportlog SET service_quantity = ('$col3'), 
service_request_id = ('$serreqid'), owner_email = ('$owneremail'), 
pi_email = ('$piemail') WHERE id = ('$id1')";

if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    echo "not updated  ";
}else{
echo "Data updated  ";
}
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: How are you setting `$_POST['id']`?

Comment: I'll work on preventing Little Bobby Tables later, thanks for the information. In my table the id is a surrogate key that I use for updating different rows.

Comment: $col8 = $row['id'];  
<input type='hidden' name=id1 class=id1 value='$col8'></input>

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later? I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."* or *"Ignore the security risk..."*.

Comment: I have not checked error logs, I am trying to figure out where those are located. And you are absolutely right about security. I need to implement protection from sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML field names do not match the names of the $_POST keys.

```
$col3=$_POST['$col3'];
```

should be

```
$col3=$_POST['col3'];
```

Comment: That works, I knew it was something simple. Thank you.

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Answer (score -2):

Use this code for updating

```
$col1=$_POST['col1'];
$col2=$_POST['col2'];
$col3=$_POST['col3'];
$col4=$_POST['col4'];
```

and

```
$sql = "UPDATE reportlog SET name = '$col3',service_request_id = '$serreqid',owner_email = '$owneremail',pi_email = '$piemail'  WHERE id = 1";
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).